# Sort, sum, and add percentages after "count" in R

Tags: r, dataframe, markdown, subset, plyr

I have a straightforward code in R that gives me the number of times a username sent a ticket request.

Data is the source dataframe, and I subsetted by request type "4"

data2 <- subset(data, q_1 == '4')

data_df_2 <- count(data2, "ticket_holder_username")

data_df_2

Attached is the image of the output in RMD. (blacked out names for privacy) [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCtRq.png)

1. How do I sort the output by the frequency?
2. How do I add another column that shows the percentage out of total tickets?
3. Is there a way to have a "Sum" of counts display at the bottom?

I am welcome to using a different package if it could give a neater output.

I have tried

```
arrange(desc())
```

but it gives is.data.frame(df) is not true.

EDIT:

Here's what I tried per https://stackoverflow.com/users/19340922/nan-yang suggestion:

[dplyr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18vq3.png)
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7a14.png)

Comment: Hi @David - Can you please share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? If you cannot share the actual data for privacy reasons, could you anonymize some of it or share a "toy" data set that is structured similarly?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function `group_by` and `summarise` in the dplyr package. In your case, you can count the frequency using this:

```
data_df_2 <- data2 %>% 
group_by(ticket_holder_username) %>%
mutate(count = n())
```

Then you can sort it from highest to the lowest using `summarise`

```
data_df_2 <- data2 %>% 
group_by(ticket_holder_username) %>%
mutate(count = n()) %>%
summarise(desc(count))
```

To add another column showing the percentage:

```
data_df_2 <- data2 %>% 
    group_by(ticket_holder_username) %>%
    mutate(count = n()) %>%
    summarise(desc(count)) %>%
    mutate(percent = count/sum(count))
```

Comment: to arrange we use `arrange` and not `summarise`

Comment: Here's what I tried: data_df_2 <- data2 %>% 
group_by(ticket_holder_username) %>%
dplyr::mutate(count = n()) %>%
dplyr::summarise(desc(count)) 
data_df_2